# fancy box overlay

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How do I get an overlay to work with fancy box? I am using the code below that I put together with my little to no understanding of jquery. I get the box to pop up fine but there is nothing in the background. I know there is some simple code somewhere that I need though for some reason I just cannot find it or I'm overlooking for it. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery  /1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.5"></script>

<!-- fancyBox buttons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=2.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.5"></script>

<!-- fancyBox thumbnails -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".vimeo").fancybox({
         width: 700,
         height: 393,
         type: 'i frame',
         'autoScale': false,
         'autoDimensions': false,
         'transitionIn' : 'fade',
         'transitionOut' : 'fade',
         'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
         'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
         'speedIn' : 600, 
         'speedOut' : 200, 
         'overlayColor' : '#E71313'
     });

     $("#various1").fancybox({
                               'title Position' : 'inside',
                               'transitionIn' : 'none',
                               'transitionOut' : 'none',
                               'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                               'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                               'speedIn' : 600, 
                               'speedOut' : 200,
                               'overlayColor' : '#E71313'
     });
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you have a couple of spaces that shouldn't be there in your link to the jQuery script

Comment: ... and this `type: 'i frame'` should be `type: 'iframe'`

Comment: Thanks. The iframe mistake has been fixed. What I am missing is the overlay. What is the proper way to code the overlay.

Comment: when you say "overlay" do you mean the modal box (fancybox) ? ... otherwise I would unserstand that you refer to the semitransparent layer (mask) that appears behind fancybox and over the content of your page. If none of the above is working, most likely exists a PATH error : the file is not where you say it was like `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery  /1.7/jquery.min.js` doesn't exist because the space or any other css or js file.

Comment: Yes I mean the semi transparent layer. The modal box works fine I just cant get the semi transparent layer. I do not get the buttons either.